React: Download Button Works, but Downloaded File Is Empty
I'm new to programming, and I've been facing some difficulties creating a download button in my React file. In short, I've built an API with Kotlin Spring Boot and tested it with JSON. Now, I'm trying to consume this API with React.
My difficulty is with the download feature. The button downloads the file, but it appears empty. However, when I inspect the element, the file appears in the 'source console' (Safari) with all its content, allowing me to save it.
Can you help me clarify why the download button does not show the PDF content? What can I do to solve this?
More information on my GitHub: https://github.com/raysatownsend/Consumindo_Api_React/blob/main/src/pages/Books/index.js
thank you!
Expect a help with my code instruction. It may be wrong.
My code is below:
export default function Books() {
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);
const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const navigate = useNavigate();

const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("accessToken");
const username = localStorage.getItem("username");

const authorization = {
    headers:{
        Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
};

const contentType = {
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "Content-Type": "application/pdf"
    }
}

const responseType = {
    headers: {
        responseType: 'blob',
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    fetchMoreBooks();
}, [accessToken])

async function fetchMoreBooks() {
    const response = await api.get(`api/books/v1?page=${page}&size=8&direction=asc`, authorization)
    setBooks([...books, ...response.data._embedded.authorVOList]);
    setPage(page + 1);
}

async function editBook(id) {
    try {
        navigate(`/books/book/new/${id}`);
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Edit book failed, please try again.")
    }
}

async function downloadBook() {
    try {
        const response = await api.get("api/file/v1/downloadFile/PRESSMAN_Engenharia_de_software_Uma_Abor.pdf", authorization, contentType, responseType)
        // Create a Blob object from the response data
        const blob = new Blob([...files, ...response.data], { type: response.headers["Content-Type"] });

        // Create a temporary anchor element
        const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'PRESSMAN_Engenharia_de_software_Uma_Abor.pdf'); // Set the download attribute with desired filename
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
        // Trigger the download by programmatically clicking the anchor element
        downloadLink.click();

        // Cleanup
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadLink.href);
    } catch (error) {
        alert("ERROR: Can't download choosen item, please try again.");
    }

}

async function deleteBook(id) {
    try {
        await api.delete(`api/books/v1/${id}`, authorization)
        setBooks(books.filter(book => book.id !== id))
    } catch (error) {
        alert("ERROR: Can't delete choosen item, please try again.")
    }
}

async function logout() {
    try {
        localStorage.clear()
        navigate("/")
    } catch (error) {
        alert("Logout failed, please try again.")
    }
}


return (
    <div className="book-container">
        <header>
            <img src={logoImage} alt="Logo" />
            <span>Bem-Vindo, <strong>{username.toUpperCase()}</strong>!</span>
            <Link className="button" to="book/new/0">Add New Book</Link>
            <button onClick={logout} type="button">
                <FiPower size={18} color='#251FC5'/>
            </button>
        </header>

        <h1>Registered Books</h1>
        <ul>
            {books.map(book => (
                <li key={book.id}>
                <strong>Title:</strong>
                <p>{book.title}</p>
                <strong>Author:</strong>
                <p>{book.author}</p>
                <strong>Price:</strong>
                <p>{Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR', {style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL'}).format(book.price)}</p>
                <strong>Release Date:</strong>
                <p>{Intl.DateTimeFormat('pt-BR').format(new Date(book.launchDate))}</p>

                <button onClick={() => editBook(book.id)} type="button">
                    <FiEdit size={20} color="#251FC5"/>
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => downloadBook()} type="button">
                    <FiDownload size={20} color="#251FC5"/>
                </button>
                <button onClick={() => deleteBook(book.id)} type="button">
                    <FiTrash2 size={20} color="#251FC5"/>
                </button>
            </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
        <button className="button" onClick={fetchMoreBooks} type="button">Load more</button>
    </div>
);

}

It's a lot of code but I see that your downloadBook function is not quite correct. You're doing unnecessary steps there.
I haven't read your full code so I don't see the point in the files array.
Here is the simplified working function which you can adapt to your needs:
async function downloadBook() {
  // fetching data from a url, getting an response if everything is ok
  // I use simple fetch here (not axios, etc)
  const response = await fetch('your url');

  // now creating a blob from response, it should have correct type automatically
  const resBlob = await response.blob();

  // Create a temporary anchor element
  const downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(resBlob);
  downloadLink.setAttribute('download', 'PRESSMAN_Engenharia_de_software_Uma_Abor.pdf'); // Set the download attribute with desired filename
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  // Trigger the download by programmatically clicking the anchor element
  downloadLink.click();

  // Cleanup
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(downloadLink.href);
}


hey @user19315471 I've tried your code, but the error still occurs... thanks for the reply!

@RaysaTownsendCarraro create a reproducible example on a site like https://playcode.io/react  someone might take a look and help you. It's hard to say anything looking at code alone
